# Users can spam votes and users will get userpoints

Tags: 7, rating

I created the following rule:

- Event: User votes on a Материал
- Condition: Check the value of the vote, greater than 0
- Action: Load points of a user, node:author
- Action: Grant points to a user, node:author 1

When a user votes on a node, the node author will get 1 user point. The same user can vote more than once, and the node author would get 1 user point each time.

UPDATE. Solved my issue by myself. Will add link to solution soon.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to vote more than once and just not give userpoints from the second vote onwards - or do you want to stop more than one vote per user and node completely?

Comment: I prefer to stop more than one vote per user and node completely. Just like on this drupal.stackexchange site

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to avoid this is to add a rule that removes points whenever a downvote happens. Same rule, different condition (if the value is -1) and different action: Decrease points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google translate to understand it (russian text):

http://webcoder.kz/modul-rate-userpoints-voting-rules-flag-dobavlyaem-bally-yuzeram-pri-golosovanii-za-nody-kotorye-oni

Comment: Seems ok although if you want a Stack Overflow style you should think on changing rate for Vote Up Down https://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down . However it's your call.